How to Simplify Peer Discovery Across a WAN in Node.js (TypeScript) Without Using libp2p?
I'm trying to implement peer discovery across a Wide Area Network (WAN) in Node.js using TypeScript. My goal is to achieve a peer discovery experience similar to bonjour or mDNS but adapted for WAN environments.I have already tried using the following libraries:
mDNS - This works well for local network peer discovery but doesn't naturally extend across a WAN.
bonjour - Offers local network service discovery, but like mDNS, it falls short when dealing with WAN environments.
libp2p - While powerful, it introduces significant complexity and overhead for my use case, making it less suitable for my needs.
I have already tried using the following libraries:
mDNS - This works well for local network peer discovery but doesn't naturally extend across a WAN.
Bonjour - Offers local network service discovery, but like mDNS, it falls short when dealing with WAN environments.
Libp2p - While powerful, it introduces significant complexity and overhead for my use case, making it less suitable for my needs.
My main requirements are:
Peer discovery over WAN with a lightweight, easy-to-use approach.
A solution that closely mimics the simplicity of mDNS or bonjour for service discovery.
Ideally, a TypeScript-friendly approach.
I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve peer discovery across a WAN with a simpler alternative to libp2p.
